# DXA Schema namespace

Tags: dxa

Can we use a Custom namespace while creating the new Schema. or do we need to use the default namespaces provided like SDL_CORE or SCHEMA_ORG

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

Note that (XML) Schema namespaces and (DXA) vocabulary namespaces are diffent things.

You can choose any XML namespace you want for your Schema; it is not relevant for the DXA semantic mapping. DXA implicitly maps all CM Schemas and their fields to the DXA Core Vocabulary (namespace if you wish).

You can also do explicit semantic mapping on the CM-side and you can map to any vocabulary namespace you wish (the vocabulary must be defined in DXA global App Data, though).

Indeed, DXA comes with two predefined vocabularies (Core and Schema.org), but again note that these are unrelated to your CM Schema namespaces.